# php DateTime() diff returns fatal error if atleast one time is bigger than 24hours

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Have some script, which is used to count how much time user spent in races. And don't need any dates, when or how much days it was, just H:i:s to return..

```
$d1 = new DateTime($time1);
$d2 = new DateTime($time2);
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
```

And it's working perfectly until I got that one racer was spent more than 25hours in races.. And getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (25:46:10) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character' in`

And also I read that datetime counts until 24hours interval.. So now looking for solution to count it not with `datetime()`

Comment: DateTime is for a fixed point in the space time continuum, not for an interval (the period between 2 fixed points in time).... its `diff()` method returns the interval from 2 fixed points. I know it's all timey wimey and subject to Tardis mathematics, but you still can't feed an interval of time to DateTime, pretending that it's a fixed point, and expect it to work

Comment: Where do `$time1` and `$time2` come from? Are you calculating them earlier in your code from fixed point in time values, or are you being fed these values to work with?

Comment: I'm getting that values from DB with `time_to_sec()` and `sec_to_time()`

Answer (score 0):

Find out my solution by writting two new functions

```
function secToTime($seconds){
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $mins = floor($seconds / 60 % 60);
    $secs = floor($seconds % 60);

    $time_format = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);

    return $time_format;
}

function timeToSec($time){
    $str_time = $time;

    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

    $time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;

    return $time_seconds;
}
```

and used them like this:

```
$time1 = timeToSec($val -> total_time_spent);
$time2 = timeToSec($first_place_time);
$diff = secToTime($time1 - $time2);
```

And it's working perfectly